# R read.xlsx gives me java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am trying to use the R package `xlsx` to load a file available at this URL:
    http://www.plosgenetics.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pgen.1002236.s019

```
library(xlsx)
filename="/home/avilella/00x/mobile.element.insertions.1000g.journal.pgen.1002236.s019.xlsx"

system(paste("ls -l",filename))
-rw-rw-r-- 1 avilella avilella 2372143 2011-12-11 16:36 /home/avilella/00x/mobile.element.insertions.1000g.journal.pgen.1002236.s019.xlsx
```

Once downloaded, I try to load it in R using `read.xlsx` or `read.xlsx2`:

```
file <- system.file("mobile.element.insertions.1000g", filename, package = "xlsx")
res <- read.xlsx2(file, 1)  # read first sheet
```

But I get an error:

> Error in `.jnew("java/io/FileInputStream", file)` : 
>         java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) make sure you're in the correct directory.  2) make life easy on yrself, and rename the file to something short&sweet w/o all the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) xlsx package.*  Try using `file.choose` which will allow you to interactively navigate to the file and thereby eliminate the possibility of misidentifying it:

```
fn <- file.choose()
DF <- read.xls(fn, 1)
```

*2) gdata package.*  If the above still does not work then you might try `read.xls` in gdata.  It uses a perl program rather than java. It can read both `xls` and `xlsx` files and can read data right off the net (downloading it into a temporary file and reading it from there in a manner that is  transparent to the user):

```
library(gdata)
URL <- "http://www.plosgenetics.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pgen.1002236.s019"
DF <- read.xls(URL)
```

`?read.xls` in gdata has more info.